# How to directly get client token in go server for push notification testing

Tags: go, testing, apple-push-notifications, huawei-mobile-services

The common way to push notification is get the token from client side, and then pass this token to the server side, finally server use this token to send any notification user want. But for test purpose, there is no actually client device, how to get the mock token from server side?

Comment: You cannot get push token without client device request for token. Instead, maybe, you can send push to topic, if you just want to receive successful status of send push request.

Answer (score 1):

@[mohax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3212712/mohax)'s answer is correct. I'd like to add a little more:

You cannot get push token without client device request for token. But you can  use [HMS Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/?ha_source=hms1) or [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/cloud-adjust/?ha_source=hms1) to test your app.

For Huawei emulator on Android Studio, you can install HMS Toolkit. As a lightweight IDE tool plugin, HMS Toolkit implements app creation, coding, conversion, debugging, test, and release. HMS Toolkit provides Cloud Debugging for you to perform 24/7 uninterrupted testing on your app running on remote real devices. With this function, you can learn about the running status of apps on Huawei devices anytime and anywhere even if no device is available, device types are not completed, or an error cannot be reproduced.

Cloud Debugging can be used on a single device for 2 hours each time. Before the validity period expires, you can release the device and apply for the device again.

For more detail about the guidance of how to use HMS Toolkit and cloud debugging,You can also refer this [link](https://medium.com/@tusharsri/debug-your-application-on-any-hms-supported-model-no-real-device-required-408a1e134782).